# Disable HTML escaping when manually rendering a Twig string

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I have the following code that renders a string into HTML output. How can I stop it from escaping the text for HTML?

```
$template = '{{ who }} bar';
$params = array('who' => "Foo's");

$twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String);
var_dump($twig->render($template, $params));
```

Outputs:

```
string(14) "Foo&#039;s bar"
```

How can I make it output this instead?

```
string(14) "Foo's bar"
```

I understand that changing `'{{ who }} bar'` to `'{{ who|raw }} bar'` will fix the problem, but I want to solve this at the rendering stage. I do not want to change all of the templates.

Comment: Do you want to disable escaping by default globally or are you looking to render only specific parameters unescaped?

Comment: No fair changing the question.  As Gerry implied, just turn escaping off globally in twig.  I'm assuming you are not generating html at all.

Comment: @Cerad I didn't edit it, which you can tell by the revision history.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I dug through the Twig code and found that this works fine:

```
$twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String, array(
    'autoescape' => false
));
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe this solution isn't better documented somewhere…

Comment: Worth mentioning that `Twig_Loader_String` is now deprecated, and `Twig_Loader_Array` should be used instead.