# Include a twig template as an object to be passed into another template?

Tags: gulp, twig

Im using gulp-twig: https://github.com/zimmen/gulp-twig

I have a twig file for my container component:

```
{# container.twig #}
<div class="container">
  {% for item in items %}
    <div class="container__item">

      {{ item }}

    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I also have a snippet file:

```
{# snippet.twig #}
<div class="snippet">
  <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
</div>
```

Im demoing these in page.twig. I need to render the snippet as the {{ item }} within the container. So when viewing page.twig this should be the output:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__item">

      <div class="snippet">
        <h2>title</h2>
      </div>

   </div>
   <div class="container__item">

     <div class="snippet">
       <h2>title</h2>
     </div>

   </div>
   <div class="container__item">

     <div class="snippet">
       <h2>title</h2>
     </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Now here is where it gets tricky. container.twig and snippet.twig are being pulled into another application. As such {{ item }} within container.twig cant be changed to something like {{ itemRenderer(item) }}.

However page.twig is not being used anywhere else so I can edit it however I like. Is there a way in page.twig to render container.twig with snippet.twig as it's item, without modifying container.twig or snippet.twig?

This is my gulp task:

```
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
  config    = require('../config'),
  utilities     = require('../build-utilities'),
  src       = config.path.src,
  dest      = config.path.dest,
  opts      = config.pluginOptions,
  env       = utils.getEnv(),
  plugins   = require('gulp-load-plugins')(opts.load);

var compile = function() {
  var notProdOrTest = env.deploy && !env.prod && !env.test,
    deployPath    = env.deployPath,
    sources = (env.deploy) ? ((env.styleguide) ? src.twig.styleguide: src.twig.testing): src.twig.all;
  return gulp.src(sources, {base: 'src/'})
    .pipe(plugins.twig({
      data: {
        component: utils.getDirectories('src/component/'),
        deploy    : env.deploy,
        test      : env.test,
        prod      : env.prod
      }
    }))
    .pipe(plugins.htmlmin(opts.htmlmin))
    .pipe(plugins.tap(function(file){
      file.path = file.path.replace('testing/', '');
    }))
    .pipe((notProdOrTest) ? plugins.replace(/src="\//g, 'src="/' + deployPath.root + '/'): plugins.gutil.noop())
    .pipe((notProdOrTest) ? plugins.replace(/href="\//g, 'href="/' + deployPath.root + '/'): plugins.gutil.noop())
    .pipe((notProdOrTest) ? plugins.replace(/srcset="\//g, 'srcset="/' + deployPath.root + '/'): plugins.gutil.noop())
    .pipe((notProdOrTest) ? plugins.replace(/url\('\//g, 'url(\'/' + deployPath.root + '/'): plugins.gutil.noop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest((env.deploy) ? deployPath.markup: dest.markup));
},
  watch = function() {
    gulp.watch(src.twig.watch, ['twig:compile']);
  };

module.exports = {
  compile: compile,
  watch  : watch
};
```

Comment: Should the snippet be rendered for all the items or only before/after the list of items?

Comment: It should be rendered for the items, I've updated my question to make this clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem. You wrote *as lots of different component can be the item within the container*, can't you add a test to use this code only when needed?

Comment: @A.L You've misunderstood my problem. Im trying to make a modular library of components that can be used in a lot of combinations. Ive updated my question so hopefully its clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I don't see how it could be possible without modifying `container.html.twig`, since you are trying to render `{{ item }}`, which is intended to be HTML, without the `raw` filter, which is mandatory to mark the content of `{{ item }}` as HTML-safe.</strike>

If you are the owner of the `container.html.twig` file origin (not sure what you meant by

> container.twig and snippet.twig are being pulled into another
>   application

), maybe you could change `{{ item }}` to `{{ item|raw }}`. Then you would just need to be sure the `items` parameter passed to `container.html.twig` contains HTML generated by a `renderView` of `snippet.html.twig`. Then just be careful `container.html.twig` is not used somewhere else with HTML-unsafe `items`.

If you really don't have your hands on it, you may also try to render your template with [a Twig environment that has `autoescape` disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990249/disable-html-escaping-when-manually-rendering-a-twig-string).

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Since you must do this using gulp-twig, what about something like this:

```
var titles = ['First snippet', 'second snippet'];
var i, items;
for (i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    gulp.src('/path/to/snippet.html.twig')
        .pipe(plugins.twig({
            data: {
                title: titles[i]
            }
        }))
        .pipe(plugins.intercept(function(file){
              items[i] = file.contents.toString();
              return file;
        }));
}

gulp.src('/path/to/container.html.twig')
    .pipe(plugins.twig({
            data: {
                items: items
            }
        }))
     .dest('/path/to/dest.html');
```

Comment: Im using gulp-twig. The other application (which is using symphony) will be using the components in a different way so its synatax cant vary greatly from what I already have for container.twig and snippet.twig.

Comment: Can you paste us your gulp script?

Comment: Updated my answer as well. Not really sure if that matches your needs, though.

Answer (score 5):

This could be done [with macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html):

```
{# macros.html.twig #}
{% macro thisItem(item) %}
    <div class="this-snippet">
        <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro thatItem(item) %}
    <div class="other-snippet">
        <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro container(itemRenderer, items) %}
    <div class="container">
        {% for item in items %}
            <div class="container__item">
                {{ itemRenderer(item) }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

And then in the template:

```
{# template.html.twig #}
{% from "macros.html.twig" import thisItem as itemRenderer, container %}

{% container(itemRenderer, items) %}
```

And in another template:

```
{# template2.html.twig #}
{% from "macros.html.twig" import thatItem as itemRenderer, container %}

{% container(itemRenderer, items) %}
```

The same thing can be achieved with regular includes, although both offer the same possibilities, I think the macro solution is cleaner.

```
{# snippet.html.twig #}
<div class="this-snippet">
    <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
</div>

{# container.html.twig #}
<div class="container">
    {% for item in items %}
        <div class="container__item">
            {% include snippetTmpl with { 'item': item } only %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{# page.html.twig #}
{% include "container.html.twig" with { 'snippetTmpl': 'snippet.html.twig', 'items': items } only %}
```

Comment: Im afraid I need to use includes as some files will include other files. I simplified the code for my example but imagine a snippet needed to include other smaller components. But maybe this cant be done and yours is the closest answer.

Comment: well, template names can also be variables, so this can also be done with includes, I'll try to add an example to my answer.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do with includes that couldn't be done with the macro solution, they boil down to the same thing, but the macros are cleaner imo.

Comment: Im sorry as yours is a good answer but my question was unclear so I've updated it again.